# Learn Sharepoint or Dynamics CRM

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm a .NET developer working in Australia. I'm planning to switch my career from .NET to Sharepoint or CRM. Any suggestion please which application has better market and what is more suitable for a .NET/web developer.
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. Why would you want to switch from programming (which has a much much wider market) to using tools and do little programming at all?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I dont want to keep doing programming that is why planning change.

Comment: This is highly opinionated, but as a current SharePoint developer who really dislike the platform, I would say current SharePoint custom development is alot of programming, and you'll have to write your code to fit into some really bad existing code. If you don't want to do programming, then don't go the SharePoint way.

Comment: @DanielB what usually sharepoint devlopment is about ? Usually what percentage is development and what percentage is configurations etc ?

Comment: It depends. For me who's built intranets and similar systems, there's a lot of programming going on to get the functionality the client wants, but theres almost equally as much configuration through declarative XML and pressing buttons in the SharePoint GUI. If you want to minimize the coding parts, you should aim to become a SharePoint administrator. The closest to programming you get there is PowerShell scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First i would say that the market for SharePoint is bigger than the market for Microsoft CRM. Nearly every Enterprise Company has SP implemented, some smaller other larger. This is my opinion.

Good CRM developers and consultants are hard to find. Therefore you would have a good daily rate when you work as a freelancer. I dont know the learning curve for CRM development.

On the SharePoint side its the same. Here you will have many developers out there but only a few which are available. We are currently seeking for about 1 year for good SharePoint developers, but could only find 1 good Junior level consultant. Currently it hard to find good experienced SharePoint developers.

But the SharePoint world is currently changing from OnPremise to Online. Many customers are thinking about Hybrid Scenarious. You would have to learn both worlds. Cause the things which are available in one world are not automatically available in the other world.

If you are a good developer with Web Development experience, then i would prefer to learn SharePoint, but its a wide system from SQL Server over IIS, SharePoint internal functionality like Services, OOTB Functionality, Server Side API, Client Side API, different Solution Types (App Model, Farm Solutions, etc.), huge differences in the versions, Workflows, Search, and many many more ...

Its nothing what you could learn in the next 6 month. If you prefer only to configure these systems, using OOTB functionaly to customize those solutions, than you will be one of many and the changes to get a good job or project will be smaller.

I think its a good chance for a .NET developer to learn additionally CRM or SharePoint. That would increase your knowledge, quality and market price. Its always good to have a look outside the box. Its a good combination. The one does not exclude the other.

Its hard to answer your question in some words. I hope, that i could give you a some idea about that. That all my personal experience and opinion.

I found a good article by Mark Rackley called [How do I become a SharePoint Developer?](http://www.markrackley.net/2014/03/12/so-you-still-want-to-be-a-sharepoint-developer/). An incomplete list of SharePoint Ressources you can find at [BOGAZCI | Sharepoint Resources](http://www.bogazci.com/sharepoint-resources/).

Good starting points are always MSDN pages like

[SharePoint 2013 development overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164084.aspx)
[Getting Started (SharePoint Development in Visual Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231568.aspx)
and [SharePoint general development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dn833469.aspx)

Comment: thanks. Are you saying I should focus on configuration all side of SharePoint ? What you have said is biggest issue for me. There are too many things in sharepoint and I don't know as a priority what I should start with ? Appreciate your help.

Comment: No! Definitly on SharePoint custom development. But not installation and setup. I think this is the admins parts. You should also know about configuring SharePoint, cause you will need to know about possible configuration options.

Comment: sorry I m asking too many things. Can you please comment in term of learning what should be priority or sequence ? Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: can you please reply my last comment. Thx

Comment: I have updated my answer. I would prefer start by understanding what sharepoint is, which ootb functionality it offers, how to set up a development environment :) and then start over with a simple webpart. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn833469